# Oracle CLOB retrieval of entire field

Tags: oracle, clob

I need to retrieve a CLOB field from oracle db

I have no problems to retrieve first n charachters (using DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR in a query works with limit to 4000 chars), but don't work if I try to retrieve largest field containing unicode chars (kanji).

Is there a method to do so?

Comment: Doesn't work how? What is the error?

Comment: If I try to retrieve fields longer than 4000 chars I obtain a "character string buffer too small" oracle error. Command is: DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(LBL_LANG, 5000 ,1)

Comment: Please show relevant code!

Comment: the relevant code is the query mentioned above: `select LBL, DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(LBL_LANG, 6000 ,1) from TABLE where LN = 'EN'`. The extended error returned is: ORA-06502: PL\/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small